# I tried to multiply 2 columns in same table and directly use the result in where statement in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Code:

```
$contributions = 
  auth()->user()->cooperative->contributions->where("amount", "<", 'amount * shares');
```

But this doesn't return required results. How can I multiply amount and shares, they are from same table and use their products.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly are the required results? I’m sure the multiplication works, but unless shares is 1 or less the condition is always true.

Comment: Yeah in shares there is 1

Comment: So how could amount be less than amount ever? Please explain exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: I changed I have 2 different tables one is for contribution with amount of money member has given and his/her shares and other table with amount required per month . Now i want to to multiply the required amount from amount table with shares from contributions table and use their result in where statements to compare with actual contribution

Comment: Please edit the question and add all the information there, including table definitions, sample data, the results you want etc.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your condition in braces and it should work fine. as below:

```
$contributions = auth()->user()->cooperative->contributions->where("amount", "<", '(amount * shares)');
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Could you explain why this would help? How does it change the situation?

Comment: Do you think it give different result?

Comment: yes, it provided different result which I have tested. Try it yourself and do let me know if it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

When you do :

```
...->contributions->where("amount", "<", 'amount * shares');
```

Laravel will not know that `amount` and `shares` are columns of the same table. It will treat `amount * shares` as a string entirely.

To let laravel consider this as a MySQL syntax, you can use `whereRaw` :

```
...->contributions->whereRaw('amount < amount * shares');
```

Another way is to use `whereColumn` :

```
...->contributions->whereColumn('amount', '<', \DB::raw('amount * shares'));
```

Hope this helps. For more check [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#where-clauses)